# Data Protection using Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2, ef-core-2.2

So I have followed microsoft's official guide (https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) for encrypting data and storing them in database using Entity Framework Core, but I can't make it work accross multiple machines. So I used Entity Framework Core implementation because in the guide says "With this package, keys can be shared across multiple instances of a web app.". The app works perfectly when using it from the deployed version for example xyz.com, but It doesn't let me interfere from localhost. Will it be a problem afterwards when my virtual machine is maxed out and I want to add another one? If so how can I make it work in both the deployed site and different machines? There is no tutorial which implements that, I have searched everywhere. Thank you very much.

```
services.AddDataProtection()
                .UseCryptographicAlgorithms(
                    new AuthenticatedEncryptorConfiguration()
                    {
                        EncryptionAlgorithm = EncryptionAlgorithm.AES_256_CBC,
                        ValidationAlgorithm = ValidationAlgorithm.HMACSHA256,

                    }
                ).PersistKeysToDbContext<DataContext>();
```

Update 12-6-2019

So I followed microsoft's documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-encryption-at-rest?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
and it states:

"If the app is spread across multiple machines, it may be convenient to distribute a shared X.509 certificate across the machines and configure the hosted apps to use the certificate for encryption of keys at rest"

I generated a x.509 certificate using this tutorial:

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1xtBkukWiek)

My updated code:

```
        services.AddDataProtection()
                .UseCryptographicAlgorithms(
                    new AuthenticatedEncryptorConfiguration()
                    {
                        EncryptionAlgorithm = EncryptionAlgorithm.AES_256_CBC,
                        ValidationAlgorithm = ValidationAlgorithm.HMACSHA256,

                    }
                )
                // )
                .ProtectKeysWithCertificate(new X509Certificate2("wibit-test-cert.pfx", "password"))
                .PersistKeysToDbContext<DataContext>();
```

When testing on my local machine it works fine, but when I deploy it, I get this error:

error: "The system cannot find the file specified"

I have tried several ways to fix it including _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath or WebRootPath. Both these ways and the one I use in the updated code work in my machine but not in the deployed app.

Any clues?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally fixed it!
The problem was that I didn't set the application name:

```
.SetApplicationName("myapp")
```

And I changed the path of the certificate to this:

```
.ProtectKeysWithCertificate(new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath,"wibit-test-cert.pfx"), "password"))
```

Also it may be a permission problem, because when I hosted the app in A2Hosting it could't find the file specified(wibit-test-cert.pfx), but when I deployed in GCP Cloud it worked!

Now I can encrypt and decrypt data using the same database with different apps.

So my final code is this:

```
services.AddDataProtection()
  .UseCryptographicAlgorithms(
      new AuthenticatedEncryptorConfiguration()
         {
             EncryptionAlgorithm = EncryptionAlgorithm.AES_256_CBC,
             ValidationAlgorithm = ValidationAlgorithm.HMACSHA256,

          }
       )
       .SetApplicationName("myapp")
       .ProtectKeysWithCertificate(new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath,"wibit-test-cert.pfx"), "password"))
       .PersistKeysToDbContext<DataContext>();
```

Comment: your approach is NOT good. You should install certificate in windows or whatever OS, and use thumbprint instead to find cert in store. .net is easy to decompile so your password is in plain text readable.
Also many people after installing gets problems because you also need to give right to IIS_USRS to be able to read certificates. (right click on certificate (in certlm app) manage private keys...)